# `sysread': end of file reached (EOFError)

Tags: ruby

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
Net::HTTP.get_print URI.parse('https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=49893')
```

I am getting an error as follows::
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:133:in `sysread': end of file reached (EOFError)
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:133:in`rbuf_fill'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:56:in `timeout'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:76:in`timeout'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:132:in `rbuf_fill'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in`readuntil'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2029:in`read_status_line'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2018:in `read_new'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1059:in`request'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:957:in `request_get'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:380:in`get_response'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:547:in `start'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in`get_response'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:337:in `get_print'
    from urlparsing1.rb:3

Answer (score 0):

I can’t reproduce the aforementioned behaviour on modern ruby version, but I think I know what causes it.

Let’s dive into execution process step by step:

```
▶ u = URI.parse('https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=49893')
#⇒ #<URI::HTTPS https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=49893>
```

OK, `URI` got.

```
▶ Net::HTTP.get_print u
#⇒ <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;
#    url=/index.php?/topic/49893-removal-instructions-for-a-fast-antivirus/'>
#  </head><body></body></html>=> nil
```

Ooups. Redirect. Let’s handle it:

```
▶ u_redir = Net::HTTP.get(u).scan(/url=(.*?)'/).first.first
#⇒ "/index.php?/topic/49893-removal-instructions-for-a-fast-antivirus/"

▶ u.path, u.query = u_redir.split '?'
#⇒ [
#  [0] "/index.php",
#  [1] "/topic/49893-removal-instructions-for-a-fast-antivirus/"
# ]
▶ Net::HTTP.get_print u
#⇒ [HTML CONTENT]
```

The summing up: I would guess you should handle redirects yourselves.

Comment: its not up to the mark dude.., help me., same error

Comment: After all, are you sure you have proper internet connection? Any proxies in between?

Comment: Everything is fine..,  I have proper internet connection..,

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=49893')


request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
         :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') {|http| http.request request}
p res.body
```